# post request from PHP to node.js(socket.io)

Tags: php, node.js, post, request, socket.io

Is it possible to make a POST request from "php" to "node.js+socket.io" and calling the appropriate method?

Code of server:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(8080);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

    socket.on('test', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        console.log(socket.id);
    });

});
```

How to call the method "test" from php?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to use fsockopen and perhaps even file_get_contents with a stream_context_create applied. But elephant.io seems to be a better solution: http://elephant.io/#usage

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to create a socket on php to connect to your node.js server. Please see http://php.net/manual/de/function.fsockopen.php

Comment: The question is how to call a specific event with post request.

Comment: I can make a request to the server, but do not know how to call the appropriate method (socket.io)?